# Why do baseball pitching machines have wheels stacked instead of side by side?

Tags: wheels

I was working on a project where I have to launch a ball. The current design has two wheels that are side by side with the ball going between them. I noticed that in almost every commercial ball launcher, the wheels are stacked on top of one another rather than side by side.

I don't understand what advantage this has over my current system. It seems a lot more accurate and precise, but I don't see why.

Comment: because horizontal precision is much more important than vertical precision.

Comment: I'm struggling to picture this - sketches would help.

Comment: Your question cannot be answered until we understand what your desired outcome is.  Why are you launching a ball, what's the intended use, etc?  There's a big difference between launching curve balls for batting practice and launching spheroids to hit military targets, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite a few of the machines allow to tilt the pair of wheels to arbitrary angle too. Some allow tuning speed of the two motors separately.

It's all about curveballs and [Magnus Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_effect). One wheel going faster will give the ball a spin on top of the forward speed - and the ball trajectory will curve in direction perpendicular to rotation axis and current velocity vector. "Stacked" layout allows to pitch the ball a longer distance, by counter-acting gravitational drop, and keeping the trajectory more straight. Sideways placement will tend to curve the ball to a side. Which you want depends on how you want to train.